# How to change setBackground color and show tick image on click a button in android

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<RelativeLayout           
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/checkimage"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/greentickmark"
            android:layout_height="16dp" />

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/clicklayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/click"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
   <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

If i click on click id Image View then layout background color is changed but check image is not visible.How to show this check image and change background color.

```
public void onClick(View v) { checkimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  

clicklayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2f0058")); }
```

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
  checkimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  clicklayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2f0058"));

 } not working.

Comment: can you post your java code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout           
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/clicklayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/click"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
       <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           </LinearLayout>

           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/checkimage"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/greentickmark"
            android:layout_height="16dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

your linear layout overlaping the imageview so..
hope this helps..